# Using parameter variables inside a function

Tags: function, variables, parameters

I have been writing a java code for duplication inside an array.
Here is the code:

```
private int[] id;
public void union(int p, int q)
{
    int pid = id[p];
    int qid = id[q];
    for(int i=0; i<id.length; i++)
        if(id[i]==pid)id[i]=qid;
}
```

But my guide said had I used `id[i]==id[p]` instead of `id[i]==pid` it would have given me an error. And went on calling it an "insidious bug". But I don't see the problem with it. It should give the same result as while I am calling that function, it should take the values I mentioned as parameters and there shouldn't be a problem.

Anybody throw some light on this please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with your code is what if `p` and `q` are out of range? You'd get an array out of bounds exception. You should first check to see if p and q are within the array's length.

Before trying to access your array with p and q, you should somehow try to check them first.

```
if(p >= 0 && p < id.length)

if(q >= 0 && q < id.length)
```

Comment: OKAY. But my concern is, even if p and q were less than my array length, would using `id[i]==id[p]` give me an error?

Comment: No it wouldn't. At least I don't see it as well, ha!

Answer (score 0):

An insidious bug will not be visible at user end but it'll continue causing problems from inside. In your code when your iteration reaches i=p, it'll update the value of id[p] and on next iteration the if condition will check for wrong value of id[p]. You won't be able to detect the error making it insidious.